# Unity 2021.3.15 Micro sized infinitely many purple/pink spots on IOS build

Tags: iphone, unity-game-engine

I migrated to Unity 2021.3.15, a month ago, from 2020.3.15. Both IOS and Android builds were working fine.

After migration, Android build works fine but IOS build doesn't.
Everything is fine on Unity editor too.

I see infinitely many small pink/purple spots on Iphone screen. Only place where these spots don't appear is on Splash Screen(right when application starts). After splash screen these pink spots appear at top of everything.
One more thing that might help to narrow down the issue, these pink spots keep flickering continuously. They are not static.

Anyone please help, I've been banging my head against wall for a month now.

Here's an image of this issue.
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Vo9HK2Mp8GiWXtCpPkDJmJjrX7dWVAog/view?usp=share_link

I tried reinstalling URP but no luck.
Tried different settings inside Project Settings -> Graphics and Player but nothing worked.

Comment: LTS Release 2021.3.25f1 is available now, maybe try upgrading. Also, do you use post processing? If so, does turning it off 'solve' the issue?

Comment: @Absinthe Post processing is not enabled. I am not using it either.

Comment: @Absinthe Thanks. I'll update to 2021.3.25. Will let you know how it goes.

Comment: Okie dokey, I'll look out for your next message.

Comment: Check the shaders you are using. Perhaps ios doesnt support the one youre picking

Comment: @BugFinder Here are the shaders that are being used. Everything worked fine on IOS when I was on Unity 2020.3.15. I don't think any new shader is added in here.
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1SysgMhtt2-DvslnrOF4_Pw-OeuOaiakd/view?usp=share_link

Comment: @Absinthe Same issue on 2021.3.25

Comment: Best to raise a ticket with Unity I think, they're usually pretty good at responding.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to fix this.
Deleted Post Processing profile and recreated it. It fixed the issue.